# I want the valueIndicator always open in RangeSlider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, rangeslider

[image: This is the picture]

I want the valueindicator to show value even not pressing or moving the slider.

Answer (score 0):

If https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_range_slider is the package you're referring to, I think you should set `showValueIndicator` to `ShowValueIndicator.always` in your `SliderTheme`.

Like this, taken from the example:

```dart
SliderTheme(
              // Customization of the SliderTheme
              // based on individual definitions
              // (see rangeSliders in _RangeSliderSampleState)
              data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                showValueIndicator: ShowValueIndicator.always,
              ),
              child: frs.RangeSlider(
                //...
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: why this package is not working.
I added prefix, still having an error when running the project.

Comment: @MiranaNightshade: please edit your question to show the code you have now.

Comment: @MiranaNightshade the prefix `frs` is not necessary. It is used like that in the example of the package.

Comment: I am also having an issue with `showValueIndicator: ShowValueIndicator.always` - it is not always showing the value indicators! (only while dragging) - any ideas how to keep them on display?

Comment: @user1048175 I think this is just the way it works. You could file a new issue at the github with your issues/feature request.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to display the value label even when the knob is released (for normal, non-range Slider). As pointed out [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/74029#issuecomment-762650622), `showValueIndicator` is not used to control the value indicator visibility when the knob is handled.
[Possible Workaround](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34704)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).